# Way to make Meetup show all events from my groups on Google calendar, without RSVP

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

I joined a few meetup groups in hopes of socializing more, and linked it to my google calendar. However it only shows events I've RSVPed to, where I was hoping it would show all events by my groups, so I can see everything I may wish to attend without having to commit yet. Anyone know if this can be changed, or if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: https://help.meetup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002879851-Exporting-an-event-to-your-calendar